# Does showing/not showing image/videos in Google admob native ad templates affect revenue

Tags: admob

I am trying to implement Google admob native ads in my app.

I am wondering whether showing images and videos in the native ads affects the revenue earned by each ad.

Does showing loaded image/videos lead to increased revenue? Or is the pricing rate for a certain loaded native ad(provided by the advertiser) fixed regardless of image/video being included in the ad?

I tried to find related information on google but sadly failed :(

Thank you in advance for your help.